# JQuery ui autocomplete не отображается результат

Tags: jquery-ui

Autocomplete делаю так:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': "")
            }
        });
   var search = $("#searchContractor").val();
   $("#searchContractor").autocomplete({
      minLength: 4,
      source: function (request,response) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {term:request.term},
        url: "https://mobilesearchContractor",
        success: function(data){
            //console.log(data);
            response($.map(data, function(item) {
                    console.log(item.contractor_id1C);
                    return {
                    //value: item.contractor_id1C,
                    label: item.contractor_name
                }
            }))
        //TODO    
        
        }
      });
        },
      select: function (item,ui) {
          
      },
      focus: function(event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // $("#subject_name").val(ui.item.label);

        $("#searchContractor").val(ui.item.label);

      }
  });
});
```

Ответ получаю такой:

```
0   Object { contractor_id1C: "00053569", contractor_name: "Филиал АО Губернские аптеки ЦГА 325 Аптечный пункт п. Стрелка ул. Первомайская 17в" }
1   Object { contractor_id1C: "00007295", contractor_name: "ПЕРЕИМЕНОВАНО ООО ФармСибКо 1 Аптека на Стрелке (г. Красноярск ул. Каратанова4)" }
2   Object { contractor_id1C: "00056798", contractor_name: "ООО Стрела Аптека (г. Кызыл ул. Дружбы 11)" }
```

На странице формируется тег UL с данными ответа, но не отображается на странице. CSS стандартный.

[image: HTML страница]